# Financial Softwares to use with CiviCRM

Tags: bookkeeping

What is the best software to use with CiviCRM?
I've been using Quickbooks premier 2015 which has no option to import transactions. 
Are there Quickbooks versions that allow for transaction import?

Answer (score 2):

I use Xero with the [CiviXero integration extension](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civixero)

Comment: Thanks @eileen. I just installed it and ran into a couple of issues which I posted in github. Looks promising though, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use Aplos Software. It's specifically for non-profit organizations with Fund Accounting. It has an api and ability to do imports.